# Dynamically created bootstrap dropdown doesn't collapse

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu, haml

In my web application there is a button which can dynamically create a DOM element having a dropdown. It is implemented using the bootstrap dropdown class. But there's an issue. The dropdown for a new element doesn't collapse once it is opened. Once I refresh the page, it works fine, only the new element created have that issue.
I inspected the code and found that the new element doesn't have an event named `hidden`. The other elements already existing have it. This 'hidden' event has a handler which is responsible toggling the dropdown(it adds/removes the sittingOnBody class from the DOM object).

Here's the haml code for the dropdown which gets created dynamically -

```
.dropdown
      %a{:'data-toggle'=>"dropdown", title: "Options"}
        %i{:icon=>"more"}
      %ul.dropdown-menu.dropdown-menu-right
        %li
          %a.chart_export Export as PNG
        %li
          %a.chart_export Export as JPEG
        - if @current_user.is_admin?
          %li
            %a.export_options Export Chart Data
        %li.divider
        %li
          = link_to "Copy Chart", select_dashboard_organization_analytics_dashboard_chart_path(@organization, @dashboard, chart.id, copy: true), class: 'fancybox fancybox.ajax'
        %li
          = link_to "Move Chart",select_dashboard_organization_analytics_dashboard_chart_path(@organization, @dashboard, chart.id), class: 'fancybox fancybox.ajax'
        %li.divider
        %li
          = link_to "Remove", organization_analytics_dashboard_chart_path(@organization, @dashboard, chart), data: {confirm: 'Are you sure you want to delete this chart?'}, method: :delete, remote: true
```

Can someone please help me solve it.

Comment: Try making a call to `$('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown()` after inserting the new dynamic element.

Comment: It doesn't solve the issue

Comment: $('.dropdown-toggle').dropdown() adds a click event to the element. But the element already has a click event. The 'dropdown' class is the one that is missing an event named 'hidden'

Comment: exactly, my thinking was that you were not listening to the events on the dynamic items, but if you are, I'm at a loss.